# Looking for a book about predator spiders living in a city

Tags: story-identification, novel

This would have been published some time in the 1970s or 1980s, I think. The basic idea is that a species of monstrous spiders move into a depressed area of a (present day) city, and start picking off the residents one by one. There's a character who investigates the disappearances, but I can't remember if they're a detective, a reporter, or a scientist.

The whole idea is *very* similar to "Wolfen", which I think I read around the same time, except with, you know, giant spiders instead of wolves.

Comment: Can you recall any other details? There may be a number of books about giant spiders hiding in cities.

Comment: Well, could this be [*The Web*](http://vaultofevil.proboards.com/thread/813/richard-lewis-web), by Richard Lewis? Some more details would definitely help though.

Comment: Doesn't sound like the Richard Lewis books, after looking them up on the web (ha!). "The Web" sounds more similar to what I remember than "Spiders", but neither quite "clicks" to me.

Comment: Can you recall any other details, then? Right now, this may be too broad to give a good answer.